# Query performance stored procedure vs individual statements

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures

I am working on a stored procedure in SQL Server which does the following.

I have the following queries in a stored procedure based on temp tables #tmp1, #tmp2

```
INSERT INTO #tmp1 (col1, col2, col3)
    SELECT col1, col2, col3 
    FROM physical1 (NOLOCK) 
    WHERE #physical1.x = y

INSERT INTO #tmp2 (col4, col5, col6)
    SELECT col4, col5, col6 
    FROM physical1 (NOLOCK)
    JOIN physical3....
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #tmp1 WHERE #tmp1.col1 = #tmp2.col3)
```

When I run individual queries to load #tmp1, and then run to load #tmp2 subsequently, the query runs smoothly and the results are pretty fast.

But when I put this as part of a stored procedure and call it from my application or using `EXEC`, the query takes a lot of time ~ approximately 200 seconds.

Total number of rows in #tmp1 and physical 1 is approximately 95000 rows.

What would be the reason for this?

I am unable to debug this issue, how to debug this and see if there are any deadlocks?

Comment: When you run it locally, are you just specifying a value for y? In which case the optimiser knows exactly what the datatype, length etc it is. Where does y come from in the stored proc?

Comment: Does it run slow for you in SSMS if you paste `SET ARITHABORT OFF;` before your code? Most client libraries connect with that setting but SSMS defaults to SET ARITHABORT ON.

Comment: @TomC The value for y is calculate is retrieved from a db table in both the cases based on a stored procedure variable. While running it in parts from SSMS, I am hard coding the value.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I haven't tried this. But executing the two queries one after the other is very fast. but running it in batch by selecting the two queries together/ running it using EXEC or running it from my application is very slow which is baffling.

Comment: It could be out-of-date statistics. Although SQL allegedly doesn't reuse #temp tables when you `drop table #tmp; create table #tmp...` it does keep the statistics for them around. It might be faster if you create an index on #tmp1.col1 and #tmp2.col3 and then update statistics with fullscan on them before running your second statement.

Comment: Show us your executions plans (or look at them yourself you may be able to work it out).

Comment: @DaleK Sure. will try to get the execution plans.

Comment: This is a very good explanation of what might be going on: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/

Comment: @TomC Parameter sniffing seems to be the culprit. Thanks for the heads up. Performance has improved after I re-assigned the parameters to avoid parameter sniffing.